# What is the algorithm OR mathematics for Fisher's Exact Test?

Tags: java, testing, statistics

I need a Fisher's Exact Test for a matrix n x m. I've been searching for hours and I've only found one example code, but it's written in Fortran. I've been working off of Wolfram and I'm close to finishing, but I'm missing the very last bit.

```
    /**
     * Performs Fisher's Exact Test on a matrix m x n
     * @param matrix Any matrix m x n.
     * @return The Fisher's Exact value of the matrix
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the rows are not of equal length
     * @author Ryan Amos
     */
    public static double getFisherExact(int[][] matrix){
        System.out.println("Working with matrix: ");
        printMatrix(matrix);
        for (int[] array : matrix) {
            if(array.length != matrix[0].length)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        boolean chiSq = matrix.length != 2 || matrix[0].length != 2;
        int[] rows = new int[matrix.length];
        int[] columns = new int[matrix[0].length];
        int n;
        //compute R and C values
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                rows[i] += matrix[i][j];
                columns[j] += matrix[i][j];
            }
            System.out.println("rows[" + i + "] = " + rows[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("columns[" + i + "] = " + columns[i]);
        }

        //compute n
        n = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
            n += columns[i];
        }

        int[][][] perms = findAllPermutations(rows, columns);
        double sum = 0;
        //int count = 0;
        double cutoff = chiSq ? getChiSquaredValue(matrix, rows, columns, n) : getConditionalProbability(matrix, rows, columns, n);
        System.out.println("P cutoff = " + cutoff + "\n");
        for (int[][] is : perms) {
            System.out.println("Matrix: ");
            printMatrix(is);
            double val = chiSq ? getChiSquaredValue(is, rows, columns, n) : getConditionalProbability(is, rows, columns, n);
            System.out.print("Value: " + val); 
            if(val <= cutoff){
                //count++;
                System.out.print(" is below " + cutoff);
//              sum += (chiSq) ? getConditionalProbability(is, rows, columns, n) : val;
//              sum += val;
                double p = getConditionalProbability(is, rows, columns, n);
                System.out.print("\np = " + p + "\nsum = " + sum + " + p = ");
                sum += p;
                System.out.print(sum);
            } else {
                System.out.println(" is above " + cutoff + "\np = " + getConditionalProbability(is, rows, columns, n));
            }
            System.out.print("\n\n");
        }
        return sum;
        //return count / (double)perms.length;
    }
```

All of the other methods have been tested and debugged. The issue is that I'm not exactly sure where to go from finding all of the possible matrices (all matrices with the same row and column sums). I'm not sure how to take those matrices and turn them into a p value. I read something about chi-squared, so I found a chi-squared algorithm.

So my question is:
From what I have (all the permutations of the matrix), how do I calculate the p value?
All of my attempts are either in the last for loops or commented out of the last for loop.

Here is the entire code: http://pastie.org/private/f8lga9oj6f8vrxiw348q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:

Looking at wolfram, it seems that n x m size problem can be solved with:

```
public static BigDecimal getHypergeometricDistribution(//
        int a[][], int scale, int roundingMode//
) throws OutOfMemoryError, NullPointerException {
    ArrayList<Integer> R = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> C = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> E = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int n = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] < 0)
                return null;

            n += a[i][j];
            add(C, j, a[i][j]);
            add(R, i, a[i][j]);
            E.add(a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    BigDecimal term1 = //
    new BigDecimal(multiplyFactorials(C).multiply(multiplyFactorials(R)));
    BigDecimal term2 = //
    new BigDecimal(getFactorial(n).multiply(multiplyFactorials(E)));

    return term1.divide(term2, scale, roundingMode);
}
```

For getBinomialCoefficient, getFactorial and comments, check out my [gist](https://gist.github.com/1030630).

Factorials grow **very quickly**, for example:

- long can store 20 first factorial values.
- [double can store 170 first factorial values](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=reduce%28n!%20%3E%20%281.79769313486231570e308%29,n%29).

Wolfram example case:

```
    int[][] a = { { 5, 0 }, { 1, 4 } };
    System.out.println(hdMM.getHypergeometricDistribution(a, 60, 6));
```

would result in:

```
0.023809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523810
```

edit 2:

My method is fast, but not memory efficient, if sum of input matrix elements exceeds 10000, this can be a problem. Reason for it is memoization of factorials.

Almost equivalent function in Mathematica, without this problem:

```
FeT1::usage = "Fisher's exact Test, 1 tailed. For more information:
    http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FishersExactTest.html";
FeT1[a_List, nr_Integer: 6] := Module[{},
   SumRow[array_] := Total[Transpose[array]]; 
   SumTotal[array_] := Total[Total[array]]; 
   SumColumn[array_] := Total[array]; 
   TF[list_] := Times @@ (list!); 
   N[(TF[SumColumn[a]]*TF[SumRow[a]])/(SumTotal[a]!* TF[Flatten[a]]), nr]
 ];
```

and example usage:

```
a = {{5, 0}, {1, 4}};
FeT1[a, 59]
```

would yield to

```
0.023809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523809523810
```

Mathematica also has statistical packages available where Fisher's Exact Test is implemented. IMHO writing this in Java can be 20% faster, but effort needed is about 200% and development time is 400%.

Comment: The link you provided only works for 2x2. In any case, I already had a copy of it (I've spent hours searching for this last step)

Comment: @Ryan Amos: I did meant to respond earlier but, I was occupied. It's good to hear, that you figured it out.

Comment: @Margus: Can you test yours against the R fisher.test function? Just let me know if your function matches the following: {1,5},{2,2},{1,3} gives 0.7602. The R fisher.test gives 0.04762 for matrix(c(5,1,0,4),nrow=2) (which is the same as { { 5, 0 }, { 1, 4 } }). I think your function may be 1 tailed.

Comment: @Ryan Amos: Yes, it is 1 tailed.

Comment: @Margus Doesn't it say something about calculating all the permutations of the matrix and arranging them? How does this work, then?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the probability equation (in LaTeX format):

The conditional probability of getting the actual matrix given the particular row and column sums, given by

[image]

```
[![\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
P &=\prod_{i=1}^r \prod_{j=1}^c \frac{n_{i.}!n_{.j}!}{n_{..}!n_{ij}}\\
 &=\frac{(n_{1.}!n_{2.}! \cdots n_{r.}!)(n_{.1}!n_{.2}! \cdots n_{.c}!)}{n_{..}!\prod_i \prod_j n_{ij}!}
\end{split} 
\end{equation}]
```

which is a multivariate generalization of the hypergeometric probability function.

[image]

If you use 100,000 iterations, and have smaller tables, say, up to 5x5, you will pretty much be close to convergence of a true exact test.

Comment: This is an old question, but IIRC the test has huge time complexity. It turns out a probabilistic/monte carlo approach is quite accurate and much faster. But yes, your answer will work for small or critical calculation.

Comment: Agree, I use MC and most of the time 10000 iterations.  And 100,000 if I want close to convergence.

Comment: I meant randomization test instead of MC, see modified answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my question. After talking with a statistician this morning, he asked me to sum up all of the values and see what came of it. I found that the sum of the values (as expected) was above 1. However, I also found that I could use the sum to scale the p-value to 0

sum of the conditional probability values of the matrices with less than or equal X^2 p-values

DIVIDED BY

sum of all conditional probability values of all matrices

I checked my answer with the R fisher exact test

Comment: is it possible to share the code of the solution? (for non-commercial use)

Comment: @Abdu Unfortunately, I probably lost it 3 laptops ago. However, you might have some luck with the R implementation: I think the fisher exact is implemented in R, though I forget exactly how to access it. Another option is to see if you can find the source associated with this documentation: http://wordhoard.northwestern.edu/userman/javadoc/edu/northwestern/at/utils/math/statistics/FishersExactTest.html